# GAE Datastore / Task queues – Saving only one item per user at a time

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, task-queue

I've developed a python app that registers information from incoming emails and saves this information to the GAE Datastore. Registering the emails works just fine. As part of the registration, emails with the same subject and recipients get a conversation ID. However, sometimes emails enter the system so fast after each other, that emails from the same conversation don't get the same ID. This happens because two emails from the same conversation are being processed at the same time and GAE doesn't see the other entry yet when running a query for this conversation.

I've been thinking of a way to prevent this, and think it would be best if the system processes only one email per user at a time (each sender has his own account). This could be done by having a push task queue that first checks if there is currently an email being processed for this user, and if so, put the new task in a pull queue from which it can be retrieved as soon as the previous task has been finished.

The big disadvantage of this, is that (I think) I can't run the push queue asynchronous, which obviously is a big performance disadvantage. Any ideas on what would be a better way to setup such a process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was a typical race-condition. I've made use of the Transactions functionality to prevent multiple processes writing at the same time. Documentation can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions